# Time complexity between appending to a Dict vs a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, time-complexity

My program currently creates a bunch of Dataframes with a specific structure. The total number of DataFrames is, for now, 88 (with up to 10k rows) ; however, this is just the testing phase with a small amount of data.

This number might increase to several hundreds of Dfs, with up to few 100k rows.

I'm concerned about scalability. I have implemented two methods to retrieve the output which is the concatenation of all these Dfs. For now, they give approximately the same result ; however, as I said, which of these will perform better ?

1. Append to a DataFrame :

   - Create an empty DataFrame df1 (with the correct structure),
   - Loop

     - Create the DataFrame of results,
     - Append it to df1,
   - Export to csv
2. Append to a Dictionary:

   - Create an empty Dict,
   - Loop

     - Create the DataFrame of results,
     - Append to Dict
   - Concat all values of the dict in a df
   - Export to csv

. which of these will perform better as the amount of data grows ? 
. does appending to a Dict gives better result than to a DataFrame although there are more steps, or the other way around, or does it give the same result ?

Answer (score 2):

**Approach2 is absolutely faster.** Pandas is quite a heavy lib I think. Maybe you should consider using `MySQL` to insert data into the database rather than `pandas` if the data is large and consumes much memory. In MySQL, you could save the data in the database rather than save them in memory.

```
import pandas as pd
from time import time
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=range(100))

#start to test approach1
approach1_start = time()
for i in range(1000):
    data_entry = ['test' for i in range(100)]
    new = pd.DataFrame([data_entry])
    df = pd.concat([df,new])
approach1_end = time()
approach1_time = approach1_end - approach1_start
print(approach1_time)
9.54729175567627

#start to test approach2
approach2_start = time()
data_entry_list = []
for i in range(1000):
    data_entry = ['test' for i in range(100)]
    data_entry_list.append(data_entry)
df = pd.DataFrame(data_entry_list)
approach2_end = time()

approach2_time = approach2_end - approach2_start
print(approach2_time)
0.021973371505737305
```

Comment: Unfortunatly, I can't use a database to store my data due to admin restriction. I can only work with csv files. But thanks a lot for your answer. I actually as doing the same as you to check. Here is the three tests I have done : (see below)

Answer (score 2):

I have done some testing in order to have an idea. Here are the testing code:

```
import timeit
import time
import pandas as pd

def timing2(f):
    def wrap(*args):
        time1 = time.time()
        ret = f(*args)
        time2 = time.time()
        print('{:s} : {:.3f} ms'.format(f.__name__, (time2-time1)*1000.0))

        return ret
    return wrap


@timing2
def withList():
    lst = []
    for i in range(100):

        df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3], 'B':[4,5,6], 'C':[90,53,64]})
        lst.append(df)

    df_new = pd.concat(lst)
    return df_new

@timing2
def withDataFrame():
    lst = []
    col_lst = ['A','B','C']
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns = col_lst)
    for i in range(100):

        df_r = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3], 'B':[4,5,6], 'C':[90,53,64]})
        df.append(df_r)

    return df

@timing2
def withDict():
    dic = {}
    col_lst = ['A','B','C']
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns = col_lst)
    for i in range(100):

        df_r = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3], 'B':[4,5,6], 'C':[90,53,64]})
        dic[i] = df_r

    lst_result = [values for values in dic.values()]
    df = df.append(lst_result)

    return df


withList()
withDataFrame()
withDict()
```

Here are the results :

withList : 76.801 ms ;
withDataFrame : 101.746 ms ;
withDict : 57.819 ms.

Comment: I tested it again with 10,000 entries and 5 runs each ; here are the results for List & Dict on average (in millisec) : 5814.2 vs 6039.4.